# What should I put in a bicycle emergency patch kit for situations more severe than a common puncture?

Tags: repair, emergency

If my bicycle breaks such as my spoke failure which lead to total tube rupture (but it could lots of possibilities) and I don't have any means to have whole bicycle carried, how can I achieve a temporary patch so I can move it a bicycle shop without further damage usually no more than 1 km? I am always riding in suburban areas. Such a kit should have components and directions and be small because there are  rare occurrences such as string trapped into the chains (almost happened once to me), minor accidents (could be caused by sudden gusts or avoiding dumb people or children).

Comment: Not quite. The answers don't deal with getting a bicycle into a state for getting to a shop.

Comment: Most of the time, you just puncture. A flat kit enables you to fix that without even going in to the shop. A broken spoke should be rare with a good wheel. If you break a spoke, a lot of people won’t have the ability to fix that. Most people might as well call for a ride.

Comment: Temp fix- there is no tag for patch on this site.

Comment: @user2617804 **that's an excellent observation**.  I was about to add, then realised patch is one of those multi-meaning words.  Posted at https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/is-puncture-a-suitable-synonym-for-patch to discuss.

Comment: The tools and spares in the linked answer, with  a bit skill and creativity,  can get practically any bikes rideable.  If those tools cannot do the job, you would need a workshop with spare parts to cover the other potential situations, - do what the pros do, have a support car with you when you ride. The ability to carry or push a bicycle means it not worth while carrying a 'just in case' workshop  for urban  riding. For long distance/remote riding unsupported, a couple of spare spokes are all I would add.

Comment: Also useful - https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/31876/what-is-the-necessary-equipment-on-longer-bike-rides?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: How remote are you planning to be? It makes a big difference. I always carry a tube, usually 2, to use in preference to patches. Then I have a tyre boot, but on long road rides I carry a folding tyre - I can be a long way from a bike shop that won't open until the next morning. I've used my tyre a few times, and regretted forgetting it.

Comment: With the road bike or cyclocross I’d be comfortable with just carrying it barefoot for 1km.

Answer (score 3):

If you only ride in suburban areas, and assess that 1km is the maximum distance for reaching a "repair point", pushing the bike is more than adequate. Otherwise, as mentioned in the comments, other answers can give you hint on what to take along.

However, if you needed additional securities, the answer is not "a repair kit", but a "b-plan":

- Public transport/taxis: you indicate that you only use your bike in suburban areas, which may well served by public transport. In some regions, you can take bikes in busses, trams or metro/subways. If you can't take the bike there, you may also lock it somewhere, use public transport and come back later (with the necessary tools and spares to fix it).
- Insurance: roadside assistance can be offered as part of bike insurance packages. If you have no way to carry your bike and depends on it for your everyday activities, it's an option to consider too.

Answer (score 1):

> if my bicycle breaks such as my spoke failure which lead to total tube rupture

If you ride on a deflated tyre, you'll destroy the tyre, then the rim. But if you push the bike a km or two, it'll be fine.

Therefore, if you ride with clipless pedals and shoes that can't be walked with, your emergency kit should include a pair of walking shoes. If you ride with oldskool pedals, or you have clipless shoes that can be walked with (like MTB shoes) then your emergency kit is already on your feet.

This also covers most mechanical failures that can't be fixed in the field with a reasonable kit (multitool, chain tool, magic chain link, inner tube, pump, patches, tire levers, etc).

Worst case, a good lock to leave the bike on the spot and walking shoes that will get you home, or to the nearest transportation/bus/train/taxi if you're far out in the woods. And a payment card XD

There's another thing missing in the standard kit: a raincoat. You can get foldable ones that are barely bigger than a wallet and weigh next to nothing. There's one somewhere in my bike kit, and the few times I had to use it, I was really glad to find it. It is wide enough to cover a backpack.

Comment: Great point on that bikes can roll even if they can't be ridden in the same state.   I carry cleat covers, and if that doesn't work I'd unbolt the cleats and walk in the shoes. I'd consider protecting the sole of the shoe with some duct tape I carry too.   Barefoot or in socks would not be considered.

Comment: Most people cycle 4 (or more) times their walking speed therefore 1 hour from home on the bike is 4 hours walking (specifics vary based on rider and terrain).

Comment: @mattnz yeah but the nearest bus station or other form of transportation won't be 4 hours away unless you're MTB'ing deep in the wilderness. Asker said he was biking in urban areas.

Comment: I mean when my MTB chainring smashed against a rock and bent, turning the bike into a kick scooter, I was glad I had walkable shoes and could push it home!

Comment: I think your answer contains an excellent reason for not using clipless shoes that can't be walked with. However, I don't find any conclusive evidence in the answer that the ideal way would be to pick stupid clipless system that doesn't allow walking with shoes and then carry a separate pair of shoes all the time.

Comment: @juhist I use MTB clipless shoes, they're walkable enough, just a bit stiff and noisy (CLACK, CLACK, CLACK). Some road bike shoes are totally non-walkable. I find the idea of shoes that can't be walked with silly, so I put MTB pedals on the bike I use on the road too.

Answer (score 1):

Puncture is the most common failure, second most common perhaps tire sidewall failure that can be fixed temporarily with tools used for fixing punctures plus a tyre boot.

Many bolts in bicycle are prone to loosening from vibration. You should be able to tighten nearly every bolt on your bike, with perhaps exception being crank bolts because once a crank bolt is loose, the press fit is already gone, and crank bolts anyway require so high force that carrying a wrench for it is not practical. Same for pedal attachment too: the tool to tighten is too heavy.

If you want the ability to remove drive side spokes on rear wheel, for example due to breaking, you need a mini cassette lockring tool such as the tool made by Stein. However, another solution could be to just zip tie the loose spoke-half and take care of it later.

Wheel truing may be necessary so you should carry a spoke nipple wrench of the proper size.

Chains do break occasionally. A chain tool is mandatory, plus either few quick links or reinforced connecting pins depending on which of these two are used by your chain.

Disc brake rotors and rims can become bent. A small 4 inch adjustable wrench can be used to straighten both, while at the same time allowing turning six sided bolts and nuts should you have any (and also the end of the reinforced chain connecting pins area easy to snap away with 4 inch adjustable wrench).

Don't carry just tools for repairing the bike. Carry tools to repair yourself. This means bandages, paper towels, antimicrobial wipes etc.

On long rides where it might rain occasionally, you could carry small plastic tubes of chain oil, allowing oiling the chain after the rain stops and the chain becomes dry and unlubricated, squeaking.